# Manipulating calendar multiple elements (td), tried .find .next .closest already

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to manipulate a basic HTML tables calendar with jquery. 
It can be found here: http://qlint.nl/bootstrap/

If you click anywhere inside a cell you will see what I'm trying to do.
Each row has 7 cells but as soon as you click further than the 2nd cell the selected days will not continue to the next row, but will just stop at the max length of the current row.

I tried everything with jquery to jump out of the current TR with .parent and move on to the next TR TD but can't get it it right.

This is the current code to fill the  with colors

```
$(function() {                       
$('td').click(function() { 
$('td').removeClass();
$(this).addClass('ochtend').next().addClass('ochtend').next().addClass('avond').next().addClass('avond').next().addClass('nacht').next().addClass('nacht'); 
}); });
```

I'm totally out of ideas. I've been trying to reach the next TD with just .next() or 'td' included. but nothing is working.

In the end I want to make all the cell TD classes move together wherever you click (like how it is on opening the page), so also current code will not do that. But that's the next problem :)

Here's the simple table HTML:

```html
    <h4 class="text-center"><b>januari</b></h4>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ma</th>
            <th>di</th>
            <th>wo</th>
            <th>do</th>
            <th>vr</th>
            <th>za</th>
            <th>zo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="ochtend">2</td>
            <td class="ochtend">3</td>
            <td class="avond">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="avond">5</td>
            <td class="nacht">6</td>
            <td class="nacht">7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ochtend">12</td>
            <td class="ochtend">13</td>
            <td class="avond">14</td>
            <td class="avond">15</td>
            <td class="nacht">16</td>
            <td class="nacht">17</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td class="ochtend">22</td>
            <td class="ochtend">23</td>
            <td class="avond">24</td>
            <td class="avond">25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="nacht">26</td>
            <td class="nacht">27</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign IDs to each td.  Then when you access each element you can access like $('#'+id).  This will ensure that your function targets the elements anywhere on the DOM.

Comment: I see, but that means I would need to add 365 IDs to all td's?
There is no way to only traverse td's?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_siblings.asp  You can try maybe nextUntil() method?  Please see that documentation there.  Hope it helps.